# cant show static files got a 404 error

Tags: python, django, pycharm

i have a problem: static files is not showing. i get a 404 error when run the project

**[30/Sep/2013 17:40:38] "GET /polls/img01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2755**

i wanna know if my project in pycharm is really reading settings.py

how can i enter in debug mode and watch STATICFILES_DIRS ?  i think its empty..

i look a lot of similar questions, and no one solution my problem. thanks for any advice!

**index.html**

```
{{ STATICFILES_DIRS }}
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}img01.jpg" alt="Hi!" />
```

**settings.py:**

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
PROJECT_ROOT + '/static/',

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

Comment: Your `{{ STATIC_URL}}` is somehow evaluating to `/polls` ?

Comment: @karthikr no, the view he's on is `/polls`, but `STATIC_URL` is evaluating to `''`, presumably because he's not using a RequestContext.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Arufielli https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles Make sure you have configured it right.

Comment: RequestContext... i used in my viewes.py  but in template index i return without RequestContext.. i will change and see what happens..

Comment: well done!! thanks a lot! like you said Daniel Roseman. the problem is that i was not using RequestConext on the return of my wiew. so i fixed:     return render_to_response('index.html', RequestContext(request, {
                                                'poll_list': poll_list}))   . thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is quite simple, he forgot to close off the `STATICFILES_DIRS` tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. usefull comment of Daniel Roseman help me to fix it.

the problem was on **views.py**

```
def index(request):
    poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('data_publicacao')
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'poll_list': poll_list})
```

so i changed to use Request context and my **views.py** now looks like:

```
def index(request):
    poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('data_publicacao')
    return render_to_response('index.html', RequestContext(request, {
                                            'poll_list': poll_list}))
```

and rendering **index.html** show me the image correctly. no more 404

thanks!